# azure function upload to blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to make an azure function that uploads to my azure blob. Reason I am trying to avoid uploading from my web server (Linux vm) is because I noticed that azure charges for data transfers (traffic from client to the virtual network linked to the VM). I was also afraid of the network traffic this would cause for the web server. Are these really issues that an azure function can fix?

For creating the function, I used visual studio and added a function with a http trigger to my blob storage. I was planning to receive a signed JWT and media content via http to the function and upload the image to the blob storage the function is currently in. I did find this code: https://www.cyotek.com/blog/upload-data-to-blob-storage-with-azure-functions
Where a new image is create in blob. However It manually connects to the blob. Since my function is already inside the blob, I was wondering if there was any way it could directly create a blob within the currently storage. This way the function wouldn't connect to the storage over the internet.

Comment: Not sure I understand your concern. If your web server (linux vm) is in the same region as your storage account, there is no bandwidth cost between them. Or between *any* resources in the same region. Azure Functions are no different. I don't see the relevance of Azure Functions here. Please edit your question to clarify. And also clarify where your web server resides.

Comment: just updated the question. It is not the traffic between vm and the blob, but the traffic between vm and the client.

Comment: i was actually looking at this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-network/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Blob Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input--output) feature of Azure Functions.

It will give you convenience, however it won't save you any traffic compared to writing the blobs manually. The good news:

- If your function is inside the same Azure region as your Blob Storage account, you won't be charged for any internal traffic
- All the inbound traffic to Azure is [free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/), 
  so you wouldn't be charged anyway

Comment: i wasn't actually worried about the inbound traffic. The traffic from client to the VM is paid whereas there is no specific charge for sending http to functions